# MySQL Query returning all fields instead of filtering

Tags: php, mysql, json

The following query is returning me all of the rows in my table instead of filtering just those that equal to the string "Marketing" in the job_category field, can't figure out why.

This is the query statement and how I'm storing the result in variables:

```
<?php

// array for JSON response
$response = array();


// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["category_selected"])) {
    $category = $_GET['category_selected'];

    $result = mysql_query('
          SELECT * FROM jobs LEFT JOIN companies
          ON jobs.company_id = companies.company_id
          WHERE jobs.job_category = $category');

// get all jobs filtered from jobs table

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // jobs node
    $response["jobs"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $job = array();
        $job["job_id"] = $row["job_id"];
        $job["company_id"] = $row["company_id"];
        $job["company_name"] = $row["company_name"];
        $job["job_title"] = $row["job_title"];
        $job["job_location"] = $row["job_location"];
        $job["job_hours"] = $row["job_hours"];
        $job["job_category"] = $row["job_category"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["jobs"], $job);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no jobs found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No jobs found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Any wonder why? This is via json call, I've tested the code for receiving just one row but not a many of rows and it works.

**EDIT** with more information:

This are the tables (sample):

JOBS:

```
+--------+------------+------------------+-------------------+
| job_id | company_id |  job_title       |  job_category     |
+--------+------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 123456 | 342186     | MySQL Dev needed | Management        |
| 549201 | 175123     | PHP Dev needed   | Marketing         |
| 784930 | 823491     | UI Designer pls  | Marketing         |
+--------+------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

COMPANIES:

```
+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| company_id | company_name |  company_email      |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+
| 342186     | Microsoft    | microsoft@email.com |
| 823491     | Quora        | quora@email.com     |
| 784930     | Facebook     | facebook@email.com  |
+------------+--------------+---------------------+
```

I'd like to return every row in the JOBS table that contains "Marketing" in job_category

Comment: not sure how your query is working takeout backticks from jobs.job_category or add backticks for tablename then to the fieldname.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I tried with and without ` it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to just put this as a comment on your original post, but don't have enough reputation yet...

You should probably use an INNER JOIN as it looks like jobs.company_id is a foreign key and there shouldn't be more than 1 result in the companies table with that id.

Also, is that actually the code?  Looks like you might be adding in the $category variable into the query?  Have you run that query by itself with actual value you're looking for in it? Does it run right in php mysql admin as pure sql?  Have you echo'd out the variable you're using to populate the query to make sure it's what you think it is?

Re: your new edit:
Try this for your sql:

```
$result = mysql_query('
      SELECT * FROM jobs LEFT JOIN companies
      ON jobs.company_id = companies.company_id
      WHERE jobs.job_category = "'.$category.'"');
```

Do this and see what you get:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM jobs LEFT JOIN companies
      ON jobs.company_id = companies.company_id
      WHERE jobs.job_category = "'.$category.'"'
echo $sql;
```

Then try to run what has been echo'd in a sql client and see if it runs. If it does, your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `*` wich means select all

try select column names manually like that:

```
 SELECT column_u_need1 , column_u_need2,....,column_u_need18  FROM jobs ........ 
 GROUP BY some_column
```

Note: if you have same name in both tables use Aliases Like that:

```
    SELECT jobs.column_u_need1 , companies.column_u_need2  FROM jobs  ........
```

EDIT: you should use INNER JOIN  , not LEFT JOIN

```
 SELECT * FROM jobs INNER JOIN companies
      ON jobs.company_id = companies.company_id
      WHERE jobs.job_category = "Marketing"
```

Comment: Hi but I need to receive multiple columns from both tables could be any, I believe the problem is that jobs.job_category apparently does not equal to "Marketing"

Comment: Special columns like 18 from 20 in both tables

Comment: yes , just select those 18 columns manually like i answered .

Comment: I just did, I'm getting the same result :/

Comment: Sir i dont understand you, you selected 18 columns so will have 18 columns , what you mean by same results ?

Comment: `*` returns all COLUMNS. In the question op is having trouble getting all ROWS when filtering with where clause - I don't think this question has anything to do with the columns returned, but the where filter not working.

Comment: thanks @MarkM i understood from you :) , then he maybe looking for group by .

Comment: @user3288852  not really sure what you are looking for but the query should work http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06c4c8/2

Comment: I mean that I need data from 18 columns to store in my variables and send back to Android. The problem here is that I need to SELECT only rows WHERE the job_category COLUMN especifically equals to "Marketing", instead I am receiving all rows with the different categories

Comment: @echo_Me sorry, GROUP BY should be placed after the WHERE statement?

Comment: if you putted sample data and wished result i could understand u better.

Comment: @echo_Me I am getting the same result unfortunately :/

Comment: @echo_Me I will edit the question with sample data in few mins will be edited

Comment: @echo_Me Thanks for taking your time, I Edited the question

Comment: @user3288852 your problem is LEFT join , you should use INNER JOIN.

Comment: @echo_Me I already tried that way, and I'm getting the same result

Comment: how same result ? look here  , http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fba7a/4  , try with inner and with left and see if its same .

Comment: @echo_Me Thanks. Looks like the statement is correct and also looks like the error is when fetching the result, I tested by defining the strings with the category sent instead of fetching and it's returning it correctly and since the query is correct, there's a problem in fetching

Comment: @echo_Me Also your code here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fba7a/4 it's returning just one field instead of the 2 rows that have the string marketing